# Eclipse won't let me add or delete string resources

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, adt

I downloaded the latest edition of the Android ADT bundle for MAC from Android Developer. However, the Eclipse plugin seems to be buggy because it won't let me add @string resources directly through the strings.xml file. On the Resources tab, when i press Add and try to add a string, it does not show up after I press okay. If i save and close the xml file, then re-open, it shows up.

Obviously, that's a hackaround and I DON'T want to waste my time doing this for every string I'm trying to add.

Does anyone have any suggestions? This seems to be a new error that I'm getting on my MAC because when I run Eclipse from my PC it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try to edit the raw xml? It has never let me down.

Just press the tab at the bottom of the screen

[image: strings.xml tab in adt]

and add a line:

```
<string name="NAME_OF_YOUR_STRING">YOUR_STRING</string>
```